# jquery validationEngine not working - jtable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-jtable

I am using jtable (jtable.org) and cannot get the validationEngine to work.

This is the error I get in my firbug console:

```
TypeError: data.form.validationEngine is not a function
```

Here is my jscript code:

```
},
//Initialize validation logic when a form is created
formCreated: function (event, data) {
     data.form.find('input[name="Name"]').addClass(
    validate[required]');
     data.form.validationEngine();
},
//Validate form when it is being submitted
formSubmitting: function (event, data) {
     return data.form.validationEngine('validate');
},
//Dispose validation logic when form is closed
formClosed: function (event, data) {
         data.form.validationEngine('hide');
        data.form.validationEngine('detach');
}
});
```

I am also including this at the top of the page:

```
<!-- Import CSS file for validation engine (in Head section of HTML) -->
<link href="scripts/validationEngine/validationEngine.jquery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- Import Javascript files for validation engine (in Head section of HTML) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/validationEngine/jquery.validationEngine.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/validationEngine/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rather than using validation engine 1 ,
i had used engine 2 
place this on control js

inputClass: 'validate[required]'

then put 
required validation js on end of jtable populate js.

hope this helps

avoid using any external js on page it may result in JQUERY.conflict() scenario